# Win creates TEMP profile after I delete local roaming profile data (Win7)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user-profiles, roaming-profiles

At my newly aquired work as a IT guy I've run into an issue with deleting local user profile data on roaming profiles.
Whenever I delete a profile on a local machine (I do it the proper way through "userprofiles", of cause), the next time the user tries to log on to the computer it creates a TEMP profile. Now I know the regedit solution to the problem (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and delete the .bak file for the user), but firstly that doesn't always work for me, and secondly it's not a very permanent solution. In the specific issue I have in front of me right now, the reg entry for the user doesn't even exist. I've read that I might have something to do with profiles on Win7 being in folders called "USER.V2", whereof the ".V2" part is not specified in the AD. Although it's not specified, the roaming profiles worked perfectly when a user logged on to new machines before the local data was deleted, so I can't see how this could be the issue. Perhaps the ntuser file might be the issue?

Are there any admins who have any ideas as to what might be causing this and how it can be solved? Would be really cool if I could fix this god-aweful problem once and for all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, I figured out the issue with the laptop. I looked in the event log, as I should have to start with, and it said that the permissions or internet access was incorrect, so all I had to do in this case was connect it to LAN and the problem was fixed... So I guess this is how you get experience... Still doesn't explain why I had the problem on desktops, as they're always on LAN.

Any thoughts and comments on the issue are still very welcome, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

after you delete the profiles, restart and if a this folder has been recreated

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\TextHarvester\TextHarvester.dat

vist this page and download the hotfix

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2866086

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue.

Comment: delete there my documents\rpf\appdata folder and desktop.ini files(desktop.ini is a hidden file) from there profile on the server and remove profile from local machine

Comment: Thanks again, but why would this solve the issue? More important than the solution, is the explanation for why this is happening. Do you know why?

Comment: if i knew why it was happening id be paid a shit load more than currently, but i know when we see usersname.temp in c:users on the local device we remove it the way you say from userprofiles then remove them from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Comment: and log in and usually temp profile issue is reolved